# react native webView paypal how tp pass the product details

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, paypal

Hi I already build an react native webView paypal i just need to know how to pass the details of the product to the Paypal its always show my the amount 1.00 USD can any one help pleas and thank you all

[the webView code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJV1t.jpg)

I prayed every thing didn't work its not passing the product details into the paypal getway

Comment: Do those buttons work and open a PayPal checkout in an approved browser view mechanism with an address bar? PayPal says to not use webviews: https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/info-security-guidelines/#link-secureapplications

Comment: Native popup bridges exist if you need them, for instance https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios

Comment: Yes it opens the PayPal checkout the think is that I don't know how to pass the product datils.

Comment: Strange, I wouldn't expect it to work. Anyway you'll need your own API for passing information to the server. Currently a client-side function is being used to create the order, actions.order.create() -- you should also change this to a server pattern https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server that calls endpoints that use the v2/checkout/orders API to create and capture an order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the prop injectedJavascript with WebView.

Build a stringified json that you will pass as follow :

```
const product = {
    title : 'Title',
    amount: 13,
}

const productString = JSON.stringify(product)

const runFirst = `let product = ${productString}; true;`
```

Then in webview pass runFirst into the injectedJavascript

```
<WebView
injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
... (other props)
/>
```

On your PayPal gateway you should have a function _createOrder already.

You can now use product.amount as follow :

```
function _createOrder(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        /* eslint-disable */
                        value: product.amount, // here is the amount you wanted to pass and that has been defined in the react native component.
                        /* eslint-disable */

                    }
                },
            ],
        });
    }
```